# Proof verification of a property of greatest integer function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof, solution-verification

The following properties of greatest integer function are given in chapter $4$ of the book *An Introduction to the theory of numbers by Niven et al.*

[image]

The proof for property $(8)$ is given as:

[image]

I tried proving $(9)$ as follows:

Let $n$ be the nearest integer to $x$, taking the smaller one if two are equally near. Then $n=x+\theta, -\frac{1}{2}\leq\theta<\frac{1}{2},$ and $-[-x+\frac{1}{2}] = -[-n+\theta+\frac{1}{2}] = n,$ since $0\leq\theta+\frac{1}{2}<1.$

Is the proof correct?

Also, are there any other methods to prove the given properties?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.